What is the effect of thickness of an elastomer sheet to its compression modules?
Can the thickness of rubber sheet significantly impact its compression modulus, which is a measure of the material's resistance to compressive forces? How thickness affects the compression modulus:

I don't think the modulus changes (a material parameter), but the mechanical response of a given shape will change, just as it will for any other material (consider compressing sheet metal vs an I-beam).
